# Set fork()'s child into foreground, and exit parent

Tags: c, terminal, background, fork, stdin

I am trying to change the PID of a process in Linux.
Then the idea is to use fork() to spawn a child, and give the control of the terminal to this child, then exit from parent.
The result would be a new process with new process PID without interrupting the execution flow.

I've coded the following PoC, but it doesn't work. If I don't use wait() on the parent, the child process doesn't take control of the terminal. I mean, it continues outputting but the stdin is not attached to the child, is owned by bash.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <asm/ptrace.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(void) {
    int i = 0, ret = 0;
    pid_t pid = 0;

    printf("PID = %d\n", getpid());
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == -1) {
        return -1;
    }
    if (pid != 0) {
        printf("Parent PGID = %d\n", getpgid(0));
        printf("Parent PGID for 0 = %d\n", tcgetpgrp(0));
        signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_IGN);
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ret = tcsetpgrp(i, pid);
        }
        exit(0);
    }
    setpgid(0, 0);
    printf("Child PGID = %d\n", getpgid(0));
    printf("Child PGID for 0 = %d\n", tcgetpgrp(0));

    for (i = 0; 1; i++) {
        printf("iter = %d, PID = %d\n", i, getpid());
        usleep(300000);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you want that the child also "blocks" the shell, so that you return to the bash command line only when the child exists?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea.

Comment: I don't know if that is possible at all, because if the parent exists (regardless whether the parent waits for the child or not), the shell will know that the parent exited and resume control and allow the prompt to be active again.

Comment: Why do you want to change the PID of the running process?

Comment: It would probably be worth checking the return value from [`tcsetpgrp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcsetpgrp.html) to see whether it works, reporting the detailed error message if it fails.  It isn't clear that trying three times is particularly beneficial.  Note that there are quite stringent requirements for the transfer of control to succeed.

Comment: @Pablo yes. I'm trying to change the PID of the process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I one call for each opened fd. 0 stdin, 1 stdout, and 2 stderr. I checked the return value, and it only returns -1 when the fd is not opened.

Comment: I know you are, I'm just asking why.

Comment: @Pablo I'm trying to bypass a tool that detects hidden pids.

Comment: I think the problem is in the execve() from bash. When executes the binary from compiling the source I shared, it returns when the parent exits. It would be possible, maybe if it only returns when all childs finishes. But that's the Linux behaivour I think... any ideas?